# Python multiprocessing when instantiation of a process locks execution

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have some python code which performs a non-collision task, no race conditions can occur as a result of this parallelism. I'm merely attempting to increase the speed of processing, I've 4 files, and rather than reading each of them one at a time I'd like to open all four files and read/edit data from them simultaneously.

I've read a few questions on here detailing that multi-threading in python isn't possible due to the Global Interpreter Lock, but that multiprocessing gets around this. For the record my code does exactly what it's meant to when I just run it four times from the terminal in separate terminals - I'm guessing this is "multiprocessing", however I'd like a cleaner programmatic solution.

The data-sets are large, so it can be assumed that as soon as a "process" is given to the interpreter, it is essentially locked for a large time period :
Example:

```
import multiprocessing

def worker():
    while true:
        #do some stuff
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

This gives me the issue in that, the above will execute the first process, and then never realistically start the second until execution is finished on the first, making them run one after the other.

Is there a way I can effectively execute worker X amount of times by either starting them at the same time, or preventing them from running until they all start? - My OS has access to 8 cores

Comment: I believe that the bottleneck is in reading the files (IO) not the CPU, creating multiple threads won't improve it. Unless you can prove that your program spends most of the time in processing the data and then it'll be interesting to see where's the bottleneck.

Comment: If i can get this working I'd be happy to attempt an empirical test

Comment: you already got it working, only that you claim it's running in serial instead of parallel. and what I'm saying is that if the bottleneck is *not* the CPU but rather reads/writes - running in parallel won't give you any advantage and might even make things worse. if you want to check it you can't avoid having "empirical tests" otherwise your decisions are based on a guess which makes it almost useless...

Comment: When the code is debugged, the second thread execution is never reached, nor does it actually ever output anything, i'm fairly sure it's not running

Comment: It should be easy enough to add a `print("I'm here", os.getpid()) ` at the beginning of `worker` and find out if the others are getting started. From your code, there's no obvious reason why the other sub-processes would not be getting started, nor why they would be serialized.